# Associate twitter account in MeteorJS and post tweet automatically

Tags: twitter, meteor, twitter-oauth

The meteorJS v0.6.4 announce that "The facebook, github, google, meetup, twitter, and weibo packages can be used to perform an OAuth exchange without creating an account and logging in."
Do you have an example of use ?

In fact, I want a user who is logged into the application can associate his twitter account and the application can then automatically tweet under his name.
I don't want to login the user with his user account but just associated it to the connected user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create this gist https://gist.github.com/Baltox/8679061 for explain how construct the OAuth signature and retrieve data from Twitter Api. 
It helped me to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you really need with these APIs, but in my project, I made use of github api... not sure if you will find it any helpful:

https://github.com/534N/miProfile

Comment: Ok, your app allows the user to connect with the Github API and then displays the information in the application meteor.
But I wan't a user already authenticated with Github can also associate his Twitter account that the system can post tweets as the user.

In summary, what is the best way to associate a Twitter account, Google account... to a user already authenticated in a meteor application.
A concrete example is zapier that allows a registered user to add a Twitter account, a Google account, a Evernote account ... using oAuth2 protocol.